# acronym/mnemonic for the uses of "por" and "para"

Tags: gramática, mnemonic

Can anyone please share an acronym/mnemonic for the uses of "por" and "para"?

I often have people ask me this but I am not aware of one. If anyone has a good mnemonic that has been effective in aiding the learning of "por" and "para", please, share.

Comment: Do you think mnemonics are a good approach when it comes to learning grammar?

Comment: I believe it's a good start. What are your suggestions, please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These have helped me a lot.

Para = PRODDS

Purpose

- Used to indicate a purpose or a goal.
- Translation: in order to

Recipient

- Used to indicate the recipient of an action or thing.
- Translation: for

Opinion

- Used to talk about an opinion.
- Translation: for, according to

Destination

- Used to indicate the destination or end point of an object or person.
- Translation: for

Deadline

- Used to indicate when something is due or scheduled.
- Translations: for, by, on

Standard

- Used to compare something or someone to a standard, such as cheapness or speed.
- Translation: for

Por = DREEMS

Duration

- Used to talk about how long it takes something to happen.
- Translation: for

Reason or Motive

- Used to indicate a reason or motive for doing something.
- Translation: because of

Emotion

- Used to indicate the recipient or or cause for an emotional reaction.
- Translations: for, towards, at

Exchange

- Used to talk about exchanges.
- Translation: for

Mode of Communication or Transportation/ Movement

- Used to talk about the manner in which something or someone travels.
- Translations: by, on, through

Substitution

- Used to indicate that someone or something is taking the place of another person or thing.
- Translations: for, instead of

Comment: I appreciate you sharing.

Comment: @Vero If you’re happy with the answer please ✔️to accept it

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. Done.